# How to prevent Xamarin.Form ListView Selected Event re-register

Tags: xamarin

I'm using listview like following at my Xamarin.Form, and I noticed a issue this code will register the listView's selected event again everytime when I use back button comeback to this page.

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
            {
        listView.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>(OnItemSelected);
// or this same issue. listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;

        }
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            Navigation.PushAsync(GotoOtherPage);
        }

 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" x:Name ="listView"  CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" AutomationId="listView">
```

My fix is following add Selected Event at xaml. However sometime I have generated the control at C#, is there other way to register event at backend C# code.

```
<ListView ItemSelected="OnItemSelected" x:Name ="listView" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" AutomationId="listView">
```

Comment: Where are you calling: `listView.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<SelectedItemChangedEventArgs>(OnItemSelected);` ?

Comment: @apineda He's doing it in XAML. `ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"`

Comment: @jdmdevdotnet no, that was the solution, before he was doing it code behind

Comment: I see. I've never seen it done like the OP is doing it though. The `listView.ItemSelected += ItemSelected`

Answer (score 2):

Having your event handler

```
void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(GotoOtherPage);
}
```

The way to do a safe subscription to the `ItemSelected` event of the ListView would be:

Subscribe your events in the `OnAppeaning` method

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    listView.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
}
```

Unsubscribe in the `OnDisappearing`:

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();

    listView.ItemSelected -= OnItemSelected;
}
```

Also notice it's not necessary to create an instance of `EventHandler` to attach the event handler to the event.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right and that's the way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should register the event in construct function, not in OnAppearing function.